# hascode and equals methods not overridden - How the put and get will work?

Tags: java, hashmap, equals, hashcode

I have a class Student and Marks.
I am using `Student` `Object` as Key for `HashMap` and Marks as Value.
If I don't override `hashMap` and equals, It still works fine.

i. Can someone please explain how does it internally works on it if not overriding both `equals()` and `hashcode()`
ii. what If I override only `hashcode()`

iii.what If I override only `equals()`

```
class Student {

    String name;
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    String lastName;

    Student(String name, String lastName){
        this.name = name;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return(" Name : " + this.getName() + " Last Name : " + this.getLastName());
    }
}
class Marks {
    Student s;
    String marks;
    public Student getS() {
        return s;
    }
    public void setS(Student s) {
        this.s = s;
    }
    public String getMarks() {
        return marks;
    }
    public void setMarks(String marks) {
        this.marks = marks;
    }
    Marks (Student s, String marks){
        this.marks = marks;
        this.s = s;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return(" Marks : " + this.getMarks());
    }
}



public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Student s1 = new Student("Vishnu","Verma");
        Student s2 = new Student("Amit","Sharma");

        Marks m1 = new Marks(s1,"65%");
        Marks m2 = new Marks(s2,"67%");

        Map <Student,Marks>map = new HashMap<Student,Marks>();
        map.put(s1, m1);
        map.put(s2, m2);

        System.out.println(map);
    }
}
```

Comment: here're some thoughts: http://www.ideyatech.com/2011/04/effective-java-equals-and-hashcode/

Comment: Joshua Bloch's "Effective Java" is the definitive answer.

Answer (score 2):

It will consider the objects equal if their references are equal. i.e. they point to the same object.

Answer (score 1):

Let us review how a `HashMap` works (in a simplistic case).

First we create our hash table:

1. we create a number of buckets - lets say 2
2. we then decide which hashcodes go in which buckets, lets say negative in one and positive (and zero) in the other.

When we add a key -> value mapping to our `HashMap` we:

1. calculate the `hashCode` of the key
2. given the `hashCode` and the above hash table we select a bucket
3. we determine if there is already something in that bucket, if there is we use a simple data structure (say a singly linked list) to store multiple key -> value mappings in the same bucket.

To get a value by key from our `HashMap` we:

1. calculate the `hashCode` of the key
2. given the `hashCode` and the above hash table we select a bucket
3. if there is a single item in the bucket we check whether they key of the mapping `equals` to the requested key, if so we return the value
4. if there is more than one item in the bucket we loop over the items in the bucket to find the first one where the key `equals` the requested key and return its value
5. if no such mapping exists we return `null`.

So, to answer your questions:

**how does it internally works on it if not overriding both `equals()` and `hashcode()`?**

I assume you mean if you do not override anything and leave it to the default behaviour.

In this case the `HashMap` uses `Object.hashCode` and `Object.equals`; the `HashMap` will behave exactly like an [`IdentityHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/IdentityHashMap.html) - i.e. it will use [`System.identityHashCode`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#identityHashCode(java.lang.Object)) to calculate the `hashCode` and it will use `==` to test for equality.

This default behaviour will only work correctly when dealing with the **same instance** of a `class`.

**what If I override only `hashcode()`?**

**TL;DR:** Your `HashMap` will behave as above.

You `hashCode` will be used to select a bucket at insertion (2) and during retrieval (2) but the default `equals` will be used to determine whether the correct key is found.

It is likely that the `Map` will work similarly to the above case, as your `hashCode` implementation is unlikely to break the general contract of `hashCode`, i.e. only the exact same instance will be equal to itself and if `hashCode` compiles with the fact that it must return the same value when it is invoked multiple times on the same instance it must by extension comply with this requirement.

**NB:** The converse is not true. Overriding only `equals` immediately breaks the contract of `hashCode` due to items that are `equals` returning different hashcodes. This will break any hash based collection from `HashMap` to `HashSet` because you will have duplicate keys and the collection will exhibit Undefined Behaviour.

This issue will be that there are many more objects that you will return the same `hashCode` for than objects that you consider `equals` - whilst this is part of the very nature of hashing, you will compound this problem.

It is likely that your `HashMap` will be inefficient in this case.

---

To illustrate what I mean consider this simple example of a `class` with one element:

```
class IntHolder {
    int value;

    //getter setter
}
```

If we use the default `equals` and `hashCode` then the our `Map` would exhibit the following behaviour:

```
final Map<IntHolder, String> map = new HashMap<>();
final IntHolder a = new IntHolder();
a.setValue(7);
final IntHolder b = a;
final IntHolder c = new IntHolder();
c.setValue(7);

map.put(a, "A");
System.out.println(map.get(a)); // --> A
System.out.println(map.get(b)); // --> A
System.out.println(map.get(c)); // --> null

map.put(c, "C");
System.out.println(map.get(a)); // --> A
System.out.println(map.get(b)); // --> A
System.out.println(map.get(c)); // --> C
```

i.e. the `Map` will only consider two keys that are `==` (such as `a` and `b`) to be the same.

If you ever "lose" a reference to a key instance you will never be able to get it back. So if you did:

```
c = null;
```

You would never, without looping over the `Map`, be able to get "C" out of the `Map` again.

**OP asks**:  *And How we determine only hashCode() need to be overridden or only equals() need to be overridden?*

You should only every override **both** or **neither** of these methods.

There is never a use case for overriding only `equals` or only `hashCode`.

Comment: @user3571396 make sure you accept an answer for each question you ask, if that question has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

If not implemented in your class, then `hashCode` and `equals` fallback to the `Object` implementations which are:

```
public native int hashCode();

public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return (this == obj);    
}
```

So the implementation of `hashCode` varies depending on the runtime environment but more interestingly regarding `HashMap`, the `equals` methods require the two objects to be the same instance to be equal!

`Object` cannot guess for you what makes two instances equal so it defaults to the strongest constraint.

Comment: Great.... Thanks...... And How we determine only hashCode() need to be overridden or only equals() need to be overridden... Not both of them ??

Comment: You might want to read about how ``HashMap`` works. It is very well documented. You usually need to implement both together. In your case, you need to answer the question: "What makes 2 students equal?"

Answer (score 0):

If you don't override equals and hashcode, the implementation is inherited from Object.

The method hashcode() is used by a HashMap to determine in a which sublist the entry will be in. So if you don't override (or even worse, override and give back the same value for each instance) the method, HashMap might store every entry in the same sublist. This will make the map slower, but putting in values will still work.

For your last question see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode--

Long story short: You shouldn't override just one. You should override both.

Comment: You're welcome. If you don't want to override yourself, for example Eclipse offers to do this for you.